# How to resolve two method calls with AnyPublisher return type into one?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have two methods with identical signature `func getItems() -> AnyPublisher<[Item], AppError>`.
First is getting items from a storage, and the second one from the internet.

How can I add such logic to the third method with the same return type, if the first method completes successfully I return `storage.getItems()`, if not I return `network.getItems()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the publisher returned from `storage.getItems()` errors out when the items don't exist, then you can "catch" the error and emit a new publisher instead:

```
func getItems() -> AnyPublisher<[Item], AppError> {
   storage.getItems()
       .catch { err in
            // check the err, if you need to
            network.getItems()
       }
       .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: And see https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsTransformersBlockers/operatorsflatmap.html#SECfailingwithoutterminating for a technique using `flatMap`.